# Discord.py How do I make my bot have a custom status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to discord.py, and I am wondering how to give my bot a custom status as I've seen other discord bots have custom status

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy with the [Client.change_presence](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=status#discord.Client.change_presence) method.

```py
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, intents=intents, case_insensitive=True)  # initialize the bot

@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await Bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online,
                                   activity=discord.Activity(name=f"Activity", type=discord.ActivityType.listening))
```

Comment: This basically achieves what OP asks about, but it should be noted that it's not really a "custom" status. Bot accounts cannot use the custom status feature in Discord, i.e. `discord.CustomActivity`.

Comment: what do I replace intents with and what does intents do?

Comment: Intents are things you want to have access to as bot, more info is here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents

Comment: await Bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=discord.Activity(name=f"Catching naughty boys; Don't get caught typing messages or chatting after 10:00 PM", type=discord.ActivityType.listening))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 1062, in change_presence
    await self.ws.change_presence(activity=activity, status=status, afk=afk)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'change_presence'

Comment: The Bot has to be replaced with your defined client, the one that at the end does `run(token)`